# PHP using out of date copy of WCF4.0 web service written in c#

Tags: c#, php, web-services, wcf

I have written a WCF 4.0 web service in C# which is using per session instance context mode.  Another developer is using PHP on a LAMP stack set up using vagrants to access this service.  After initial and successful connection attempts I have modified the service, but we cannot access the new functions with PHP.

Accessing the service URL from a browser retrieves the new WSDL.  Why is the PHP unable to detect the changes.  We are using: `public array SoapClient::__getFunctions ( void )` to get the interface of the service but it will not update.

Answer (score 0):

In the SoapClient call you just need to add the parameter
 ‘cache’ => WSDL_CACHE_NONE